# How to get details of a certain list element?

Tags: android, for-loop, exception, android-espresso

I have a list view, containing several rows with same Id; each row has several different components. Here an extract of the hierarchy (all with visibility=VISIBLE):

```
->ListView{id=213, res-name=listview, child-count=2}
-->RelativeLayout{id=214, res-name=bground, child-count=5}
--->AppCompatTextView{id=215, res-name=name, text=Short}
--->AppCompatTextView{id=216, res-name=valid, text=10.04.}
--->... further elements in the RelativeLayout res-name=bground
-->RelativeLayout{id=214, res-name=bground, child-count=5}
--->AppCompatTextView{id=215, res-name=name, text=Group}
--->AppCompatTextView{id=216, res-name=valid, text=09.04}
--->...
```

I want to loop over all first level elements in this list (all RelativeLayout elements with res-name=bground) and check the name attribute; once I have found the element that I search for (e.g. name=Group), I want to check its other attributes.

My current coding is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    String type = getDataText(allOf(withId(R.id.name),
        childAtPosition(
            allOf(withId(R.id.bground),
                childAtPosition(withId(R.id.listview),i)),
            0),
        isDisplayed()));
```

where getDataText is:

```
String getDataText(final Matcher<View> matcher) {
    final String[] stringHolder = { null };
    onData(matcher).perform(new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isAssignableFrom(TextView.class);
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "getting text from a TextView";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            TextView tv = (TextView)view; 
            stringHolder[0] = tv.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    return stringHolder[0];
}
```

In the execution of the loop shown above, I get a AmbiguousViewMatcherException, where listview is marked as problem. I suppose it means that Espresso has found ambiguous children in the listview element (what is true), but childAtPosition should take only the element specified by the position index.

How can I implement the loop correctly?

Thanks and best regards
Gerhard

Answer (score 0):

You can add isDisplayed() to your adapterview matcher to interact with the currently visible listview.

inAdapterView(allOf(withId(android.R.id.list), isDisplayed()))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I did not get it working.

Comment: Meanwhile I found this:
The app shows three tabs (the first is visible on the screen), all three have the attribute visible=VISIBLE in the view hierarchy. And really the first and also the third tab contain a listview element. 

I expected that this should solve:

`    ... allOf(childAtPosition(
             allOf(childAtPosition(
                 childAtPosition(
                     withId(R.id.pager), 1),
                 0), isDisplayed()),
             0) /* = listview */, isDisplayed()), ...
 
Can you please explain again your solution?

Thanks and best regards
Gerhard